# 1 Script 2 Terminal in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to start a part of code in one terminal (for example from line 1 to 26) and another part in another terminal? (from line 27 to 48)? Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: Why don't you split the code into two files, then, and execute one in each terminal?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? Be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: Because the two pieces of code refer to the same program. I am working on linux and I need a terminal to start a service that must remain active and another to connect to this service. Normally I would have to manually start the service in a terminal by running the command and then connect to the latter with the second terminal. If it comes in handy I'm using pymetasploit which will run on the second terminal

Comment: The problem is that if I try to start the service using os.system () to launch the command in the terminal, Python loses control over the terminal and cannot continue executing the program that foresees the use of that service.

Answer (score -1):

You could use command line arguments.

In your first terminal call `python3 my-program first`
And in your second terminal call `python3 my-program second`

Then in your code you will need something that looks like:

```
import sys

if __name__=="__main__":
    if sys.args[1] == "first":
        ... #lines 1 to 26
    elif sys.args[1] == "second":
        ... #lines 27 to 48*
```

Did this answer your question? (the name *first* and *second* are just examples, feel free to change them)

Comment: Can I start the two terminals in sequence with this code? I need to start the service first and then the script. Should I simply copy it and insert the two pieces of code under the two ifs? Now I'm not at home so I can't test.

Comment: Yes, just copy the piece of code in the correct place, then launch first the one you want to be launched at first. Open a new terminal and launch the second one (with the use of the arguments)

Comment: I would like to understand why my answer ins't useful. Can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: It wasn't me, also because I haven't tried it yet and my reputation isn't enough to rate it